# fzaninotto/faker Can you set random $count quantity of randomElements?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using [this package](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to seed test data in my Laravel project.

For on field I am using this;

```
randomElements($array = array ('a','b','c'), $count = 1) // array('c')
```

My question is 2 parts;

a) can you make the $count value random?  For example between 1-3.

b) I am using json_encode to avoid Array to string conversion but now values are being stored with ["example1", "example2"], how do I remove the [""]?

I understand storing arrays is not ideal but development has gone too far down this road.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of an answer for b), but for a) I just did this:

```
$faker->randomElements($array = array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), $count = $faker->numberBetween(5, 10))
```